# Схема предложения с однородными членами

Tags: синтаксис

Горная тундра пестрит яркими цветами, такими как оранжевый, красный, бордовый, белый, зелёный.

Очень хочется знать, как правильно сделать схему предложения. Учитывая однородные члены и союз "такими как". Или "такими как" это не союз?

Answer (score 0):

*Горная тундра пестрит яркими цветами, **такими как** оранжевый, красный, бордовый, белый, зелёный.*

**Основа:** тундра блестит, блестит цветами (дополнение), яркими цветами (определение), горная тундра (определение).

**Обособленное определение**: цветами (какими?) **такими как** оранжевый, красный, бордовый, белый, зелёный.

Здесь союзное соединение: ***ТАКИМИ КАК*** (указательное местоимение + союз КАК).

Сравнить: *Горная тундра пестрит **такими** яркими цветами, **как** оранжевый, красный, бордовый, белый, зелёный.*

Схема: ~ — = ~ --, такими как ~ ~ ~ ~ ~.

Answer (score 0):

**Такими как** это не союз, это указательное местоимение + союз.

Насчет союза:

```
Вася ушел, как Петя // союзное слово
Как Петя, Вася ушел // союз 

Вася был такой какой надо // союзное слово
Вася был такой как надо // союз
```

Насчет схемы

```
Из комнаты вышел Вася, или Петя  // сложное
Из комнаты вышел Вася или Петя   // простое
```